# Why does an element have the same attribute twice with a different value?

Tags: html, css

I am new to web scripting and I don't understand why `top` is given twice in the code below:

```
<div id='divErrorDictionarySearch' style='position:absolute;top:10px;height:100%;width:90%;left:20px;top:20px;'>
```

Why is it given twice? Which value will be used?

Comment: Hi there, I see you haven't cast a vote on this question yet, if you feel that your doubt was resolved please take a moment to accept the best answer by clicking the green check mark next to it. Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

Second value will overwrite the first one by CSS cascading rules

You can read the w3c documentation on CSS cascading [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order)

Comment: is there any specific reason to give two values or it may be done while applying patches?

Comment: could be a patch, but most likely someone overlooked it, I would consider it incorrect to leave both values

Answer (score 1):

2nd one because of the css rules.